# Determining whether a user arrived from Google (and the query he used if so)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From within my Rails app, how do I determine whether a user arrived on a given page by clicking a Google (or Bing or Yahoo) search result?

If the user arrived in this fashion, how do I determine what search terms he used?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

```
referer = @request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

then, parse the info you're looking for (site, query) from that string.